# Unable to add dll file reference to F# project in VS2008

Tags: f#

I can't seem to add a reference to a DLL file in F#.  It might be a bug with Visual Studio.
I attempted to add a reference to my F# project by clicking on "Add Reference" ->  "browse".  I found my DLL, and when I attempted to add it, nothing happened. The window didn't even close to confirm my selection.  Help please.

Answer (score 1):

Are you adding a reference to a managed DLL?

Anyways, if you can, make a small repro and send it to fsbugs AT microsoft dot com.

Edit: Here's the list of [known issues with the F# Sept CTP](http://blogs.msdn.com/lukeh/archive/2008/09/17/f-september-2008-ctp-known-issues.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

I think there are some known issues when the DLL is produced by Managed C++, however I don't know the details. In any case, sending a bug report to the F# team as Michael suggests is the best thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a reference to the F# project never works for me, i need to debug the project, then i reference the resultant dll found in the debug folders. This usually does the trick for me.

When I reference the project it always tells me that there is no dll.